# undefined reference to `boost::chrono::system_clock::now()' - Boost, and cpp-netlib

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, undefined-reference, c++-chrono

I come here to ask for a fix to a situation that has been frustrating me. A lot.
First of all, I'm on Windows, I use MinGW as a compiler (C++).

I've been having some problems with getting a program to work with the use of cpp-netlib and SSL (trying to POST to a https site). I believe everything is in order except this one error that keeps evading me.

`C:\boost_1_50_0\boost_1_50_0\stage\lib\libboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_50.a(thread.o):thread.cpp|| undefined reference to 'boost::chrono::system_clock::now()'`
I'm sure that I've linked to chrono, as well as all the .a libs in `BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib`. I've tried re-ordering so chrono is linked before thread. Nothing helped.
I've tried definining the `BOOST_CHRONO_INLINED` in my IDE settings and multiple `conf.hpp`s to make it header only, which didn't help.

I'm pretty sure this is a newbie question and I hope that someone can give me a quick fix. I've written this in a rush because I have to be somewhere but if you need more info please say so and I can write it more carefully when I get home. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I've tried re-ordering so chrono is linked before thread.

That's wrong. Boost.Thread depends on chrono, so chrono needs to be linked *after* thread, so the linker knows which symbols are needed and can find which library defines them and link to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have a go at trying this when I get home, but I do recall, before reordering, that chrono was linked after thread. I'll see.

Comment: You should post the full linker command then, otherwise everyone's just guessing what you might have done or not done