# Unresolved external symbol boost::chrono::system_clock::now(void)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost

google has been unkind...

I recently pulled down boost 1.50, and am trying to build my project using it. It's a large project, using several boost features (threads, signals, pointer classes, spirit, etc.). Some specifics:

- MSVC 9.0 (2008)

- Static linking boost

I'm getting an error linking every resulting exe, but with chrono, which I'm not directly linking. The error is:

```
libboost_thread-vc90-mt-sgd-1_50.lib(thread.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class boost::chrono::time_point<class boost::chrono::system_clock,class boost::chrono::duration<__int64,class boost::ratio<1,10000000> > > __cdecl boost::chrono::system_clock::now(void)" (?now@system_clock@chrono@boost@@SA?AV?$time_point@Vsystem_clock@chrono@boost@@V?$duration@_JV?$ratio@$00$0JIJGIA@@boost@@@23@@23@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall boost::thread::try_join_until(class boost::chrono::time_point<class boost::chrono::system_clock,class boost::chrono::duration<__int64,class boost::ratio<1,1000000000> > > const &)" (?try_join_until@thread@boost@@QAE_NABV?$time_point@Vsystem_clock@chrono@boost@@V?$duration@_JV?$ratio@$00$0DLJKMKAA@@boost@@@23@@chrono@2@@Z)
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575660/undefined-reference-to-boostchronosystem-clocknow-boost-and-cpp-net), but I'm not directly controlling the order of linking (rather using the auto-link capabilities). If there's a specific lib I'm missing, I can manually link it; sub-optimal, but possible. However, I have no idea what's missing. It appears (to my semi-educated view) that the symbol is externed in the chrono lib, and not in the system lib.

Any help?

Comment: Update: I managed to work around the problem by explicitly including thread, chrono, and system (in that order) at the lowest level. I'd still like to know if there's a "better" solution, though, especially since I don't even use chrono directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/build.html). It specifies that you have to link to chrono and system to use thread unless you give some specific macros to disable their use (and lose their functionality).

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's a good of answer as any. I guess I just expected boost to "handle it automatically" with linking, whereas in this case if you just include boost::threads (or include in the wrong order) it fails to link. Good to know, though.