# Linker error: Boost.Chrono to Boost.Timer

Tags: boost, linker-errors

I'm trying to get a simple example working with Boost.Timer for some stop watch performance measures and I can't figure out why I'm unable to successfully link between Boost.Timer over into Boost.Chrono. I built boost from source with the following simple script

```
.\b2 --clean
CALL bootstrap
.\b2 --build-type=complete address-model=64
```

But still wind up getting a linker error.

```
70>libboost_timer-vc100-mt-1_49.lib(cpu_timer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class boost::chrono::time_point<class boost::chrono::steady_clock,class boost::chrono::duration<__int64,class boost::ratio<1,1000000000> > > __cdecl boost::chrono::steady_clock::now(void)" (?now@steady_clock@chrono@boost@@SA?AV?$time_point@Vsteady_clock@chrono@boost@@V?$duration@_JV?$ratio@$00$0DLJKMKAA@@boost@@@23@@23@XZ)
```

Is it necessary to actually include the `--with-chrono` flag to use the Timer class? Can't find anything relevant in the Timer [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html) although the Thread [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/thread/build.html) seems to mention more which I was lead to from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962219/unresolved-external-symbol-boostchronosystem-clocknowvoid) which suggests something about an order of linking fix.

It's a bit confusing since I see the assemblies built and ready to link to in Visual Studio via the project setting `Linker->General->Additional Library Directories`. I think there's something about the design of Boost that's not obvious in how its handling these particular libraries. Can anyone comment on this? What's the deal with `--with-chrono` / `USES_CHRONO` macro, it doesn't appear to prevent the library from being built so is it conditionally compiling out some code, specifically the time_point class?

I would think according to Table 30.1. in the Thread documentation ~Default Values for Configurable Features" that `USES_CHRONO` is Yes by default so I should have these features enabled right?

```
C:\...\boost_binaries\msvc10_x64>dir /b | findstr /i chrono
boost_chrono-vc100-mt-1_49.dll
boost_chrono-vc100-mt-1_49.lib
boost_chrono-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.dll
boost_chrono-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib
libboost_chrono-vc100-mt-1_49.lib
libboost_chrono-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib
libboost_chrono-vc100-mt-s-1_49.lib
libboost_chrono-vc100-mt-sgd-1_49.lib
libboost_chrono-vc100-s-1_49.lib
libboost_chrono-vc100-sgd-1_49.lib

C:\...\boost_binaries\msvc10_x64>dir /b | findstr /i timer
boost_timer-vc100-mt-1_49.dll
boost_timer-vc100-mt-1_49.lib
boost_timer-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.dll
boost_timer-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib
libboost_timer-vc100-mt-1_49.lib
libboost_timer-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib
libboost_timer-vc100-mt-s-1_49.lib
libboost_timer-vc100-mt-sgd-1_49.lib
libboost_timer-vc100-s-1_49.lib
libboost_timer-vc100-sgd-1_49.lib

C:\...\boost_binaries\msvc10_x64>dir /b | findstr /i _system
boost_system-vc100-mt-1_49.dll
boost_system-vc100-mt-1_49.lib
boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.dll
boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib
libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_49.lib
libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib
libboost_system-vc100-mt-s-1_49.lib
libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_49.lib
libboost_system-vc100-s-1_49.lib
libboost_system-vc100-sgd-1_49.lib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the link order does resolve it, which I've set in the project setting `Linker->General->Input->Additional Dependencies` which suggests that Visual Studio has some scheme for how it goes chasing after linker dependencies given a directory that somehow conflicts with either how the boost dependencies are made or how I'm using boost in my source.

We have the habit in house of just pointing to additional directories and letting the linker figure it out, but I guess that's not robust enough for all libraries. Interesting stuff order of linking, I'd like to know how the default behavior is defined in Visual Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214489/linker-error-with-boost-1-60-and-vs-2013-on-x64). Answer was to:

```
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
```

Comment: aha, I thought I remember something coming up during work about Chrono being a "header only" library. I'm not entirely sure the details but if it's true then I could see including the header as being sufficient.