# Linker error with Boost 1.60 and VS 2013 on x64

Tags: c++, qt, boost, cmake

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer s;
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled this above mentioned code in qt with msvc 12.0 x64 and it throws the following error:

```
libboost_timer-vc120-mt-gd-1_60.lib(cpu_timer.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class boost::chrono::time_point<class boost::chrono::steady_clock,class boost::chrono::duration<__int64,class boost::ratio<1,1000000000> > > __cdecl boost::chrono::steady_clock::now(void)" (?now@steady_clock@chrono@boost@@SA?AV?$time_point@Vsteady_clock@chrono@boost@@V?$duration@_JV?$ratio@$00$0DLJKMKAA@@boost@@@23@@23@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::get_cpu_times(struct boost::timer::cpu_times &)" (?get_cpu_times@?A0x0d396f6a@@YAXAEAUcpu_times@timer@boost@@@Z)
debug\Test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Boost has been compiled in architecture x86 and address model 64 with the following command line argument-

```
b2 toolset=msvc-12.0 --prefix=<location> --build-type=complete --abbreviate-paths architecture=x86 address-model=64 install -j4
```

Also, the program runs fine when compiled with 32 bit msvc 2013 compiler, and I am using Qt Creator. This is the content of my project file -

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp


win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += "-LD:/boost/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib/" -llibboost_system-vc120-mt-1_60 -llibboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_60 -llibboost_timer-vc120-mt-1_60
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += "-LD:/boost/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib/" -llibboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_60 -llibboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_60 -llibboost_timer-vc120-mt-gd-1_60
else:unix: LIBS += "-LD:/boost/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib/" -llibboost_system-vc120-mt-1_60 -llibboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_60 -llibboost_timer-vc120-mt-1_60 

INCLUDEPATH += D:/boost/boost_1_60_0/
```

Comment: You're not linking (the correct version) of the libraries. Boost Chrono and System aren't header-only and perhaps your project definition finds the 32bit libs

Comment: I've edited the question with more details.

Comment: Now, I'm witnessing a miracle. Even if I remove those lib and include paths, still the program compiles fine in 32 bit. The only thing that has changed is that the include line (with the boost header) in the main source code shows no such file or directory is found, on mouse hover, with a green curvy line underneath.

Comment: So it's taking the libs from somewhere else.  There are no miracles. :(

Comment: I renamed my old boost directory, it's showing that the old boost directory not found. Can't change the dependency location to the new boost directory. Need Qt guys to help me.

Comment: Of course you can. What does Qt have to do with linking the wrong boost version? If anything you need a  CMake guy here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102730/discussion-between-a-aniq-and-sehe).

Comment: What is your CMake version? Show us please the output of CMake's boost check.

Comment: msvc uses nmake to compile, check this build log (http://pastebin.com/9TqMjzu9) if it can help. Also, how to do boost check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had *exactly* the same issue in VS2015.

The solution for me was to:

```
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
```

Hope this helps somebody else!

Comment: It did help me ! Voted you up.